# Printing a malloc'd pointer always gives the same address

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, printf

Am I printing it wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main( void )
{
    int *       p = malloc(100000);
    int *       q;

    printf("%p\n%p\n", (void *)p, (void *)q);

    (void)getchar();            /* to run several instances at same time */

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Whether I run it sequentially or in multiple terminals simultaneously, it always prints "0x60aa00000800" for `p` (`q` is different, though).

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers, one of the reasons I was confused was because it *used* to print a different address each time.  It turns out that a new compiler option I started using, `-fsanitize=address`, caused this change.  Whoops.

Comment: `q` is going to be somewhat random since it's not assigned. You'll get whatever's on the stack. The funny thing when I run this multiple times in the same Linux bash terminal, the `p` address comes out different each time, but the `q` address is always the same.

Comment: You're printing the pointer address correctly.  Are you wondering why it's always the same for the malloc()?

Comment: Try a different compiler and OS, then maybe it gives different result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `q` is uninitialized garbage, since you never assign a value to it.

It's not surprising that you get the same address for `p` each time you run the program. That address is almost certainly a *virtual* address, so it applies only to the memory space of the currently running program (process).

Virtual address `0x60aa00000800` as seen from one program and virtual address `0x60aa00000800` as seen from another program are distinct *physical* addresses. The operating system maps virtual addresses to physical addresses, and vice versa, so there's no conflict. (If different programs could read and write the same physical memory, it would be a security nightmare.)

It also wouldn't be surprising if they were different each time. For example, some operating systems randomize stack addresses to prevent some code exploits. I'm not sure whether heap addresses are also randomized, but they certainly could be.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: when can we get the corresponding physical memory then? After the pointer is used ?

Comment: @Bionix1441: A program running in user space never sees physical memory addresses. All memory access is via virtual addresses.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not entirely surprising.  The `malloc` operation is simply returning a pointer to user addressable + allocated memory in the process.  It's completely reasonable for the first memory request of the same size to return the same address through different invocations of a process

The behavior for `q` doesn't contradict this.  You have given `q` no value hence it gets whatever the last value written to that portion of the stack was.  It's unsurprising that undefined behavior would be different through different invocations of the same process (after all, it's undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.

The same code, and the same algorithm for obtaining memory with malloc() is run each time, so there's no reason the addresses should be different.

- Some malloc implementations could randomize the start of memory allocations, yours does not.
- This is because of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The physical memory address for memory of `q` is different, but your operating system provides each process with a virtual view of memory, mapping different physical memory addresses to the same virtual addresses in your processes. So all processes have a similar view of the memory (and cannot see the memory of other processes)

Answer (score 1):

Heap allocators are not required to provide distinct / unique addresses each time you run the program. There is no guarantee either way on this, but it's entirely reasonable for an implementation of `malloc()` to have deterministic behavior and give you the same pointer each time you run the program.

The *stack*, on the other hand, usually is (but is not required to be) located at a different address. This is a [protection measure against buffer-overflow exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Implementations). By making the stack location non-deterministic, they make it more difficult for an attacker to inject direct memory addresses of code via buffer-overflow attack.

Finally note that all pointers in a program are virtual memory addresses, not physical addresses. So even though two concurrent processes might have the same memory address in a pointer, those two processes still have distinct memory in separate areas of physical memory. The operating system takes care of this via its virtual memory manager and page translation. Each process has its own virtual address space, various pieces of which are mapped transparently by the OS to physical memory as needed.